# How to obtain a solution for the following IBVP?

Tags: thermodynamics, boundary-conditions, differential-equations, convection, heat-conduction

I am trying to solve the following advection-diffusion equation for transient flow conditions for radial flow.

The governing equation is as follows.
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1-2v(t)}{x} \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}$$
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} + \frac{f(t)}{x} \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}$$
where
$$f(t)=1 -2 v(t)$$
Initial condition
$$T(x,t=0)=0$$
BCs.
$$T(x=0,t)=1$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} T(x,t)=0$$
I have tried to solve the problem using the following solution procedure.

Assume the solution takes the following form.
$$T(x,t)=\left ( e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}\right) F(t)$$
The similarity variable $-\frac{x^2}{4t}$ is appropriate selection for solving diffusion equation for radial flow.

The partial derivatives of $T(x,t)$ are as follows.
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} =-\frac{x}{2t}\left ( e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}\right) F(t)$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} =F(t)\left( -\frac{1}{2t}\left ( e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}\right) + \left( \frac{x}{2t} \right)^2        \left ( e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}\right) \right)$$
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \left (\left( \frac{x}{2t} \right)^2 e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}\right)F(t) +  \left ( e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}\right)\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$$
By substituting into the governing equation, the following ODE in $F(t)$ is obtained.
$$\frac{dF}{dt}=-\left ( \frac{1 + F(t)}{2t}\right)F(t)$$
The solution of the ODE is as follow.
$$F(t) = \exp\left ( -\int_{0} ^{t} \left ( \frac{1 + F(u)}{2u}\right) \, du\right)$$
Finally, the solution of the governing is as follow.
$$T(x,t) =\left ( e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}\right) \exp\left ( -\int_{0} ^{t} \left ( \frac{1 + F(u)}{2u}\right) \, du\right)$$
This solution is the same as that given in Handbook of Linear Partial Differential Equations for Engineers and Scientists - Page 367 (when $a=1$)(https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/9780429166464). Unfortunately, this solution satisfies the initial condition as well as the outer BC, however it doesn't satisfy the inner BC. When x is put equals to zero, the resulting solution will be as follows.
$$T(x = 0,t) = \exp\left ( -\int_{0} ^{t} \left ( \frac{1 + F(u)}{2u}\right) \, du\right)$$
My question is how to use the given solution to obtain a solution that satisfies the governing equations, initial conditions, and all boundary conditions of my problem. The resulting solution seems to be a solution of the same problem, however with time dependent inner BC. Duhamel's integral can be used to obtain a solution for time-dependent BC problem given the corresponding solution for constant BC problem, however the problem here seems to the opposite. Can anyone give me a hint of how to proceed to obtain the solution that satisfies the inner BC?

Comment: Your boundary conditions, namely T(0,0) is ambiguous. I think you would require a more complicated superposition solution to achieve the given BCs.

Comment: The boundary conditions are T(x = 0, t) = 1 & T(x--> infinity,t) = 0. I think the boundary conditions are simple. I am not sure I understand your comment. @Lelouch

Comment: But you also have $T(x,t=0) = 0$. Then there is an ambiguity at $T(0,0)$ if I am not wrong.

Comment: What is the actual physical problem?

Comment: The problem describes heat transfer by advection (fluid movement) and conduction during radial fluid flow in semi-infinite model and the advection velocity (or fluid rate) is time dependent. The problem assumes uniform initial temperature and sudden change in temperature at the inner boundary at t > 0.@ChetMiller

Comment: Yes. T(0,0) =0 and at t > 0, T(x=0,t) =1. Can you give hint for the solution using superposition. @Lelouch